# How to check differential equations solutions invariance under some reflection?

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

Let's say I have system of differential equations:

```
   system = {u[x, y] D[u[x, y], {x}] + u[x, y] D[u[x, y], {y}] = 0,D[u[x, y], {x}] + D[u[x, y], {y}] = 0}.
```

The Solution of this equation is invariant under u->-u reflection.

How can these be checked with a code, that system is equal to {-u[x, y] D[-u[x, y], {x}]  -u[x, y] D[-u[x, y], {y}] = 0, 
 D[-u[x, y], {x}] + D[-u[x, y], {y}] = 0} reflected system.
Is there any solution for this independent from dependent and independent variables of differential equation?

Comment: I'm not seeing a derivative anywhere...

Comment: @J.M. edited that parts, but the solution will not be depdendent on that, that's why I wasn't concentrated on that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Reduce[D[u[x, y], x] == 0 && D[-u[x, y], x] == 0]
```

**Edit**

To address your question formulated in the comment:

```
eq1 = D[u[x, y], x]*v[x, y] == 0;
eq2 = D[-u[x, y], x]*v[x, y] == 0;
Reduce[eq1 && eq2]
```

[image]

which is exactly equivalent to eq1.

Have fan!

Comment: Works.
Thank you

Comment: In case I have D[u[x, y], x]*v[x,y] == 0, it doesn't help, because it gives possible 0's, which doesn't let me to check invariance. It works only for euqations with single multiplier.

Comment: Have a look at the edit. However, I guess that in reality your equations are much more complex than those trivial that you put in your question. May be, it is useful to give this realistic equation to see once your problem as it is.

Comment: I didn't see edit version. So you can see question with edited equations.
Thank you.

Comment: @Davit Shahnazaryan  Sorry, I retype.

Comment: Sorry again for not giving the real equations, now you can see edited.
But after your edition what I thought, maybe to check the equality of Reduce results.
For example Reduce[system1] === Reduce[system2], it will work and if there is some equations not reflected, iwe will see the difference in the results.
What do you think ?

Comment: @Davit Shahnazaryan  I do not know. You should try and see, if it works.